# Crash when JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, string>>

Tags: c#, dictionary, serialization, jsonconvert

#### Error

> An unhandled exception of type 'Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException' occurred in System.Private.CoreLib.dll

> Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: S. Path '', line 0, position 0.

#### The json

```json
{
   "Australia":"36",
   "Austria":"12",
   "Belgium":"2",
   "Bulgaria":"15",
   "Canada":"37",
   "China,mainland":"39",
   "Croatia":"21",
   "Cyprus":"16",
   "Czech Republic":"29",
   "Denmark":"10",
   "Estonia":"17",
   "Finland":"9",
   "France":"4",
   "Germany":"3",
   "Greece":"18",
   "Hong Kong SAR":"44",
   "Hungary":"19",
   "Ireland":"20",
   "Italy":"7",
   "Japan":"40",
   "Latvia":"22",
   "Liechtenstein":"43",
   "Lithuania":"24",
   "Luxembourg":"23",
   "Malta":"25",
   "Monaco":"42",
   "New Zealand":"38",
   "Norway":"32",
   "Poland":"8",
   "Portugal":"14",
   "Romania":"26",
   "Singapore":"47",
   "Slovakia":"28",
   "Slovenia":"27",
   "Spain":"6",
   "Sweden":"5",
   "Switzerland":"41",
   "The Netherlands":"1",
   "United Arab Emirates":"35",
   "United Kingdom":"13",
   "United States":"30"
}
```

My string is saved on a `Properties.Resources` inside my project. Running this makes the program crash:

```
var test= JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, string>>(UTF8.GetString(Properties.Resources.country));
```

code link: https://dotnetfiddle.net/o1Z3uv

Comment: Try saving `UTF8.GetString(Properties.Resources.country` to a variable and check to see if that looks like the expected JSON.

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce your issue (without using UTF8.GetString()): https://dotnetfiddle.net/TFdy1Q. Can you provide a [mre]?

Comment: Hi @juharr, thanks for your reply. I just did that and it exactly looks the same, also both jsons work on https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/#

Comment: @gunr2171 I added a dotnetfiddler link, somehow is working there, but locally on my net core 3.1 project it crashes.

Comment: I would verify that the string is being loaded like you expect from Resources, and that it is still valid JSON (quotes escaped properly).

Comment: @JesseMcConahie I run the code like it is on the dotnetfiddle example and it crashes still, I don't know what to do tbh.

Comment: @EmanuelRodriguez Which dotnetfiddle example does crash? The one that is provided in the question works fine. Change `Console.WriteLine(dict);` to `dict.Dump();` to see the parsed values.

Comment: @PeterCsala theres no example that crashes, the issue is that online example doesn't crash, but on my computer does, and its the exact same.

Comment: @EmanuelRodriguez Can you please amend your question to include the result of `UTF8.GetString(Properties.Resources.country)`?  Please also try to fetch the value like this `Properties.Resources.ResourceManager.GetString("country");`

Comment: @PeterCsala I just confirmed that it was an issue with the type of the framework, still no solution on net core 3.1. I tried the code in the net framework and it works straight away. but on Net Core it crashes. I don't understand.

Comment: If you're using NuGet Packages, try uninstalling and reinstalling the Newtonsoft package. If the NuGet package was installed targeting the wrong framework, sometimes that can cause issues. This can happen if you converted your app from Framework to Core.